# Creating a Client/Service in Netflix Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

With regards to the Netflix Eureka Service Registry, I have setup the Eureka Netflix Server using Tomcat 8.0.35 successfully. I have also got the basic  [Example Service & Client](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/tree/master/eureka-examples) to communicate with each other. I'm still new to Eureka and the management decision is to use Eureka with Spring as several new applications are written around the Spring framework.

I have been following the wiki in order to understand how the communication works (But with little to no success with registering services).. [Eureka Github Wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-eureka-client-server-communication).

My question is: Do I need to create my own Eureka Service & Client in order to maintain a registry of about 50 cloud instances? (If so, can you please point me in the right direction).

I have hands on experience with Consul/RESTfull API, and have implemented Consul in production (using php, and qbit); however the Netflix Eureka Registry look's as though I need to learn eureka/spring + client/server java programming? I'm still getting used to the following terms.

1. **Eureka Server** (I successfully got this working using Tomcat8/JDK1.8 + the eureka.war)
2. **Eureka Service** (Some kind of stand-alone RESTfull service that queries the Eureka-Server and listens for client requests)
3. **Eureka Client** (Java snippet to be embedded into the Java servlets/jsp)?
4. **Zuul** (A type of routing/load-balancing app - similar to HaProxy ?)
5. **Ribbon** (A type of routing/load-balancing app - similar to HaProxy ?)

I would like to get the Service & Client configured for mostly non-AWS cloud instances. The Eureka Wiki is not very helpful when it comes to creating a working eureka service & client. Any help to point me in the right direction to implement a Eureka based RESTfull system would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read this documentation about spring-cloud : http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html

It should be a good start to setup a few simple spring-boot/spring-cloud services and start to use advanced tools like zuul/ribbon/hystrix ...

Comment: Thanks. I'll follow those instructions.

Comment: @user133417, please consider accepting the answer above if you consider it correct

Answer (score 0):

There is [a simple example](https://github.com/agritsik/distributed-system-rest) of distributed system using Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Netflix.

This project contains the following microservices:

1. **requestor** and **responder** which communicates via REST/HTTP
2. **gateway** microservice - Spring Boot app + Zuul
3. **discovery** microservice - Spring Boot app + Eureka

Moreover, requestor microservice uses Hystrix library.

As you can see, Spring Cloud provides a really good wrapper for Netflix solutions. As a result, you can start quickly with minimal configuration.